# Is there a standard definition for plant "maturity"?

Tags: plant-physiology, life-history

Is there a species-agnostic metric for identifying plant maturity?

There seems to be plenty of literature defining life-history stages for specific crops, but it is not clear if there is a generic definition.

In the context of crops, I would like to be able to identify the stage at which plants are no longer exhibiting juvenile traits.

Comment: Exactly what types of traits are you looking for? First onset of flowering seems to me to be an obvious choice, since sexual maturity is the definition of being an adult. Do you find this insufficient, and if so, why? It is generally easier to use "positive" definitions (presence of traits) than "negative" ones (e.g. lack of juvenile traits).

Comment: Also, I realize that some plants only reproduce clonally, but this should be less of a problem(?) in crop plants.